# How to use Schema registry for Kafka Connect AVRO

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have started exploring Kafka and Kafka connect recently and did some initial set up .
But wanted to explore more on schema registry part .

My schema registry is started now what i should do .

I have a AVRO schema stored in avro_schema.avsc.

here is the schema

```
{
  "name": "FSP-AUDIT-EVENT",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "VERSION",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "ACTION_TYPE",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "EVENT_TYPE",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "CLIENT_ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "DETAILS",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "OBJECT_TYPE",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "UTC_DATE_TIME",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "POINT_IN_TIME_PRECISION",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "TIME_ZONE",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "TIMELINE_PRECISION",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "AUDIT_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_PITP",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TZ",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TP",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "GROUP_ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "OBJECT_DISPLAY_NAME",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "OBJECT_ID",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "USER_DISPLAY_NAME",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "USER_ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "PARENT_EVENT_ID",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "NOTES",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SUMMARY",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is my schema is valid .I converted it online  from JSON ?
where should i keep this schema file location i am not sure about .
Please guide me with the step to follow 
.
I am sending records from Lambda function and from JDBC source both .

So basically how can i enforce AVRO schema and test ?
Do i have to change anything in avro-consumer properties file ?

Or is this correct way to register schema

```
   ./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
                 --broker-list b-3.**:9092,b-**:9092,b-**:9092 --topic AVRO-AUDIT_EVENT \
                 --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'





curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"     --data '{"schema" : "{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":false,\"field\":\"ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"VERSION\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"ACTION_TYPE\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"EVENT_TYPE\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"CLIENT_ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"DETAILS\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"OBJECT_TYPE\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"UTC_DATE_TIME\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"POINT_IN_TIME_PRECISION\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"TIME_ZONE\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"TIMELINE_PRECISION\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"GROUP_ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"OBJECT_DISPLAY_NAME\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"OBJECT_ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"USER_DISPLAY_NAME\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"USER_ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"PARENT_EVENT_ID\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"NOTES\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"SUMMARY\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_PITP\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TZ\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TP\"}],\"optional\":false,\"name\":\"test\"}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/view/versions
```

what next i have to do

But when i try to see my schema i get only below

```
curl --silent -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/AVRO-AUDIT-EVENT/versions/latest
```

this is the result

```
{"subject":"AVRO-AUDIT-EVENT","version":1,"id":161,"schema":"{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":false}"}
```

Why i do not see my full registered schema

Also when i try to delete schema

i get below error

```
{"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"
```

i am not sure if my schema is registered correctly .

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

> is my schema valid

You can use the REST API of the Registry to try and submit it and see...

> where should i keep this schema file location i am not sure about

It's not clear how you're sending messages...

If you actually wrote Kafka producer code, you store it within your code (as a string) or as a resource file.. If using Java, you can instead use the SchemaBuilder class to create the Schema object

You need to **rewrite** your producer to use Avro Schema and Serializers if you've not already

> If we create AVRO schema will it work for Json as well .

Avro is a Binary format, but there is a JSONDecoder for it.

> what should be the URL for our AVRO schema properties file ?

It needs to be the IP of your Schema Registry once you figure out how to start it. (with `schema-registry-start`)

> Do i have to change anything in avro-consumer properties file ?

You need to use the Avro Deserializer

> is this correct way to register schema

.> `/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \`

Not quite. That's how you produce a message with a schema (and you need to use the correct schema). You also must provide `--property schema.registry.url`

You use the REST API of the Registry to register and verify schemas

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for replying ...As usual its you only who takes Kafka learning to next level for people like us .So My schema registry is running good .But as you said i need to keep it into resource file .Can i know where exactly ?I do not have any code just configs .Second when you say i have to rewrite producer what does that mean in context of JDBC connector ?I have to change that only propeties for that ?

Comment: Also when i read topic from JDBC i still see jason format only

Comment: 1) *JavaScript Object Notation* is not written "jason". 2) You must configure AvroConverter in the connector properties to get Avro data. The source connector is a type of producer. 3) Kafka Connect creates its own schemas, so you don't need to worry about those

Comment: So i just have to use property file ..Data from JDBC will be converted by connector into AVRO ?I did config changes and started my schema registry and then connector ...But when data is inserted into JDBC and i tried to read from the topic i miss some data ..All columns are not displaying

Comment: It should pull all columns by default. But if you are using avro console consumer, then it's working, and the problem exists elsewhere

Comment: Its not working ..I get this error `org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Must provide the Avro schema string in value.schema` ...

Comment: Please see the last part of my question ...I am not able to register avro ..Do i need to download avro converter ?

Comment: That error comes from the Avro console producer. Why are you trying to produce data on your own? And AvroConverter comes with Confluent Platform. If you installed via APT/YUM then you'd have it

Comment: Just one more question ...Can i have JSON schema fixed for all messages ?If a message which does not fit to that schema should be discared

Comment: The jdbc source manages schemas on the it's own, not only as json. It should be allowed to add and remove columns. If you have constraints on invalid values, you should be using triggers or embed that logic in your code to prevent data from being added

Comment: i am still not able to implement AVRO schema .I have schema i have modified AVRO properties file but still not able to use or star it

Comment: @AtharvThakur Why not? Have you read the quickstart about how to use `kafka-avro-console-producer`? https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/quickstart.html

Comment: yes  i did everything ...Can i update my question with all steps i did ?

Comment: You can, but according to the current post, you have no `value.schema`, like the documentation says to have

Comment: Edited my question ..Please help me with step for AVRO .

Comment: I think i am on right track ...Please have a look and Guide a little bit

Comment: You wouldn't use the Producer just to register a schema https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/using.html#common-sr-usage-examples You applications will fail when sending messages using the Avro serializer that don't match that schema

Comment: So i have registered my schema also ..I get verison when i do curl ...Can i post my messages now ?

Comment: Sure. You don't need to ask me for permissions. You can always try on your own

Comment: still i am not able to make this work ..when i try to see my schema i get only few parts .Also not able to delete schema.I am not sure if my schema is registered correctly ..I have updated my question with the details as well .

Comment: Looks like you used `kafka-avro-console-producer`, which will register the schema for you, which you should **not** do. And Schema Deletion works fine in Confluent Platform 4.0+. `curl -X DELETE http://registry:8081/subjects/name`

Comment: No i have used `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"     --data '{"schema" : ` to register schema

Comment: And Kafka Avro console producer does the same thing internally. If you provided the correct schema, that does not answer how you got something different in the registry

Comment: so then what should be correct way to register ...Can you please have link here ..Cai i follow the same thing ..He ha schema aslo in his avro folder https://github.com/datastax/kafka-examples/blob/master/producers/src/main/java/avro/avro_example.sh

Comment: using curl (or POSTMan) is the proper way to register, as you've already said you did. Putting schemas in your code allows you to write a producer, not register them

Comment: So i have to register and then i have to use that in code as well ..Or can i write producer code without schema ?

Comment: Avro requires a Schema. You can have the producer use that schema and do a registration on its own, **but** it is highly recommended to actually POST the schema yourself